# SmartGwt - Excel like cell based focus in SmartGwt

Tags: smartgwt, smartclient

I am trying to implement an MS-Excel like functionality in SmartGwt where i can navigate through various cells in a ListGrid using keyboard and edit cells individually.

Currently it is only possible to navigate the grid at a row level, and all editable cells go into edit mode together.

We have a grid that shows stock market data with fields for price, symbol etc. The last field is a button, and users want to navigate to this button using the arrow keys and press enter to execute a buy/sell order.

Thanks for helping